# Where to store oauth2 access/refresh tokens using a native (windows) desktop client?

Tags: windows, security, oauth-2.0, desktop-application

When implementing oauth2 authorization code grant flow, what would be the best practices for storing the access and refresh tokens between sessions? The client is a native windows desktop application.

My initial thought was storing the tokens in the windows registry after encoding them using the windows [Data Protection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata), with a hard-coded secret (entropy in DPAPI). This is rather simple to implement although I'm not sure if it's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use built in operating system secure storage, which will use storage private to your app and user. For Windows use the `Windows Credential Manager` - see the screenshots in my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/).

My example desktop app is coded in Node / Electron and uses the [Keytar Component](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/tokenStorage.ts) to interact with WCM.

The [Keytar Home Page](https://github.com/atom/node-keytar) provides more info - and you can then follow the same pattern if using different tech.